# Java library containing Spring MessageSource and message properties files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a shared library containing some UI components for Spring (Boot) applications.

I want the library to contains the translations for the text of its own components.
My idea was to create a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` in the library, along with the message properties files containing the translations.

I create the message source like this:

```
    this.localMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    localMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    localMessageSource.setBasename("mymessages"); // I have also tried "classpath:mymessages"
```

And I have tried putting the `mymessages.properties`, `mymessages_nl.properties` etc. files in `/src/main/resources` and in `/src/main/resources/META-INF`, but when calling the code that accesses this `MessageSource` to get the messages, they are not found.  In the debugger, I can see that the resource bundle is not found at all.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: Just distribute a JAR with the `messages.properties` and let the regular Spring Boot MessageSource handle things. Your additional will actually disable autoconfiguration for the `MessageSource` which probably will surprise consumers of your library.

Comment: @M.Deinum 1) what path does the properties file need to be placed, 2) I did not configure this local message source as a bean so the autoconfiguration was not disabled

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following method:

- The service that uses the library has its own `MessageSource` bean which is a `ResourceBundleMessageSource`
- The library code has a resource bundle e.g. `mymessages` in `/src/main/resources`
- At an appropriate place in a bean that is configured in the library code, add the basename for this resource bundle to the injected `MessageSource` like this:

```
((ResourceBundleMessageSource)messageSource).addBasenames("mymessages");
```

In my case, in the library I have a singleton bean which implements `com.vaadin.flow.i18n.I18NProvider` and delegates the `getTranslation()` method to the `messageSource.getMessage()` method, so the constructor of this bean is an appropriate place to add the base name for the additional resource bundle to the already configured `MessageSource`.